# Expand C: with another Hard Drive?

Tags: windows, windows-8, partitioning

I have two hard disk of 30GB each.

- (First Hard Disk - 30GB) [C:] **Windows 8**
- (Second Hard Disk - 30GB) [D:] Free

I would like to use the second hard disk to expand the space of my first hard disk.

Is there anyway to do this? (Without having to reinstall everything?)
Windows 8 after 2 days has already used 25GB.

Be Aware: **they are NOT** on the same HDD.

Comment: You need a bigger hard drive, 60gb will eventually be too small over time.

Comment: You can create a fakeraid in Disk Management.

Comment: They seem pretty small to me, and running Windows 8... Are you sure they're two hard drives and not 1 hard drive with several partitions?

Comment: @kobaltz: can you explain that? Also are you sure I can span C:\ partition over another HDD?

Comment: @xandy: they are 2 SSDs

Comment: Ahh, it makes sense now.

Comment: You could make the D drive a mount point but that'd be atypical.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Natively, you can't. If it was a raid before installing Windows, you could use two hard drives and extend, but you can't do so after Windows is installed, on the boot drive.

Comment: Considering RAID: Can I do it without using RAID 0 ?

Comment: With dynamic disks, you can, but not on the boot drive

Answer (score 27):

**This doesn't work if the partition you are extending has Windows on it, since Windows labels them as a `Boot` drive and they can't be extended across other disks. The only solution would be to use a hardware RAID at this moment.**

There is no need for third party utilities this time, for that you'll have to convert your disks to what Windows calls "dynamic disk" and then extend the volume across disks.

This would be the procedure:

1. Press <kbd>[image]</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to bring the power user menu up and then <kbd>G</kbd> to open the computer management console.
2. Go to `Disks Management`, you'll see something like this (but without that 2nd partition in the first drive and the 3rd disk and maybe with a System Reserved partition):

   [image: Disks overview]
3. Right click `Disk 0` and select to convert it to a dynamic disk:

   [image: Converting to dynamic]
4. In the process choose the second disk aswell:

   [image: Choosing both disks]
5. After the conversion is done, right click the volume where Windows is and select to extend the volume, add the second disk in:

   [image: Extending to another disk]
6. `Next` and `Finish` and you're done, your Windows drive would be extended using the second disk as well.

Comment: This seems GREAT! But when I do right click on C:\ I don't have Convert to Dynamic Disk WTF ??

Comment: Hmm... are you right clicking the C volume? You have to right click the disk itself.

Comment: Ahh got it! Sorry

Comment: I did it. Now both Disk are yellow. But I don't have the extend volume option (it's disabled =/ )

Comment: Do you have any partition in the second disk? The disk has to be empty.

Comment: I have only one partition on the second hdd http://i48.tinypic.com/rtp2lt.png I will delete it now. Wait I can't delete D:\

Comment: It seems i can't delete the only partition on D:\ drive...

Comment: I can see in your picture that there's a paging file in that partition, maybe that's why you can't delete it... So maybe you have to delete the paging file before it allows you to delete it. I can try that out but it'll take me a while. See http://www.advicehow.com/manage-virtual-memory-in-windows-8/

Comment: I will try to move out the paging file to first hdd and retry

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6350/discussion-between-xandy-and-yes123)

Comment: Sorry, did this work for the C:\ drive? Because I'm wanting to do it to my 28GB SSD, but I don't want to brick my netbook. Does it cause any issues etc.? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Check out Storage Spaces. Paul Thurrott has an [excellent article](http://www.winsupersite.com/article/windows8/windows-8-feature-focus-storage-spaces-142537) on it. In short, hit the Windows key and type 'Storage Spaces'.

I am not sure if you can add drives to the C: drive however, so this might not be the answer you seek.

Comment: Unfortunately can't work on C:\... At this point I believe i just can't do it

Comment: Reviews I've seen said storage spaces had rather poor write performance for software raid.  Unless/Until that's fixed I'd be leery about using it.